# Can someone explain this ASM program?

Tags: assembly, x86

I've got this ASM program. It's simple but I need help explaining it.

```
code_segment SEGMENT
assume cs:code_segment
a1:call subroutine
a2:inc ax
a3:call subroutine
a4:inc bx
   mov ah,4ch
   int 21h

subroutine proc near
   mov ax,0
   mov bx,0
   ret
subroutine endp

code_segment ends
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has literally been over 20 years since I've done *any* assembly programming but taking a stab at what I remember on this...

1. zero out the registers ax & bx (subroutine proc near)
2. increment the AX register
3. zero out the registers ax & bx (subroutine proc near)
4. increment the BX register
5. move the value 0x4C into the AH register
6. invoke the DOS 0x21 interrupt with which will interpret the value in AH as exit the program.

Comment: Not bad for someone so out of practice.  I would add that the value in `AL` (which got set to zero as part of zeroing AX) would be the exit value for the program and that the value in BX is unused.

Comment: …And that the code is extremely silly and poorly written. If this is something that a teacher provided, they are doing their students a serious disservice.